# nginx proxy_pass with flexable subpath possible?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, proxy, url

currently I have this as my `proxy_pass` which works fine

```
    location = /sms/resetpass {
             proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/resetpass;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

the above works fine but I figured if I want another proxy such as

```
    location = /sms/sample1 {
             proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/sample1;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

then I have to make another `location block`

is it possible to do something like this?

```
    location = /sms/something_here {
             proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/something_here;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

where `something_here` means if I pass in any url into `sms/blah` then the `proxy_pass` would be `api/blah`

I tried to google something like `proxy_pass with subpath` or something like that but doesn't seem to be what I need.  So I am wondering if this is possible or I just didn't know the right word to find it?

Thanks in advance for any advices.

Comment: First do this in your testing site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use nginx `location` and `rewrite` directives, something like this should be fine:

```
location ~ ^/sms/ {
    rewrite ^/sms/(.*) /api/$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4;
    ...
}
```

don't forget to test it first.

Comment: nice, I tested it out...seems to be wording fine :D thanks a lot